# Ext.getCmp(id) or Ext.ComponentQuery.query(attribute)

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am new to Extjs and using Extjs v4.2.0.

To find an object I can use either `Ext.getCmp(id)` or `Ext.ComponentQuery.query(attribute)`.

Which one is better to use and faster?

Comment: focus on the 'better' and worry about 'faster' only if what you are doing turns out to be slow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best is to avoid using any of this two directly. `Ext.getCmp` is especially considered bad "code smell". You should strive to organize your code in such a way that you don't need them.

Component queries are elegant, but you should use them either from a [parent container](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Queryable-method-query) (thus reducing the research tree and allowing you to leverage relative [`itemId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId)), or from a [controller](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#). It is my guess that controllers are the true reason why component queries have been added to Ext4.

Answer (score 3):

`getCmp` will be faster, since it's a simple hash lookup. When you use `query`, it has to parse and then execute the query, so for a simple id only, `getCmp` is better.

However, be wary of using id's, since they need to be globally unique. It's only a good idea to use them in cases when you know there will only be one, for example a login window, or your main app container.