# Is Ext.ComponentQuery.query a time consuming process to access component

Tags: extjs4.2

Currently i am using Ext.ComponentQuery.query method to access components using id.So just wanted to know if it is safe (proper) way to access components.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Id` the `Ext.getCmp` is probably better\faster option then component query.

As stated on [other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871798/ext-getcmpid-or-ext-componentquery-queryattribute?rq=1),

> be wary of using id's, since they need to be globally unique

Using them in your code makes your components really hard to reuse (you cant create two instances of component on the same page for example). For reasonable complex ExtJS app I strongly suggest to use MVC app architecture. Although MVC model in ExtJS 4.x is far from perfect and i personally use [DeftJS](http://deftjs.org/) which offers not just improved MVC model but also IoC and Promises and community support is awesome!